# Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using visual basic 2012, i have created a web services with following code.Where i have two method `GetConnection()` and Insert(). I getting connection ihave wrritten the code to get the database string.In Inert method i
am inserting the value into EMP table with following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader sdr;

    public string name
    {
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
    public string dept
    {
        set
        {
            dept = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return dept;
        }
    }
    public string adress
    {
        set
        {
            adress = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return adress;
        }
    }
        public int salary
    {
        set
        {
            salary = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return salary;
        }

    }
        public string email
        {
            set
            {
                email = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return email;
            }

        }
    public WebService1()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add any constructor code required
        //
    }

    // WEB SERVICE EXAMPLE
    // The HelloWorld() example service returns the string Hello World.

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public void GetConnection()
    {
        string c = "Data Source=navse-win81_1;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        con = new SqlConnection(c);
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public int Insert(Test obj)
    {


        GetConnection();
        string query = "insert into Emp(Name,Dept,Salary,Addres,Email)values(@na,@Dt,@sa,@ad,@em)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@na", obj.name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", obj.dept);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sa", obj.salary);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad", obj.adress);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", obj.email);

        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return a;
    }
}

public class Test:System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public string name
    {
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
    public string dept
    {
        set
        {
            dept = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return dept;
        }
    }
    public string adress
    {
        set
        {
            adress = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return adress;
        }
    }
    public int salary
    {
        set
        {
            salary = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return salary;
        }

    }
    public string email
    {
        set
        {
            email = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return email;
        }

    }
}
```

When i am trying to access this web service in web browser getting following error:

```
Server Error in '/Projects' Application.

Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface.

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 

[NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface.]

[InvalidOperationException: Cannot serialize member 'System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent.Site' of type 'System.ComponentModel.ISite', see inner exception for more details.]
   System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.CheckSupportedMember(TypeDesc typeDesc, MemberInfo member, Type type) +5640106
   System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetPropertyModel(PropertyInfo propertyInfo) +122
   System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetFieldModel(MemberInfo memberInfo) +89
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter) +247
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter) +378
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter) +5641243
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter) +378
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter) +5641243
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter) +378
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +1734

[InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'Test'.]
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +1852
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +5648048
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMemberMapping(XmlReflectionMember xmlReflectionMember, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +869
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +286

[InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting 'obj'.]
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +899
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(String elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, XmlMappingAccess access) +133
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, Boolean serviceDefaultIsEncoded, Boolean rpc, SoapBindingUse use, SoapParameterStyle paramStyle, String elementName, String elementNamespace, Boolean nsIsDefault, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean validate, Boolean openModel, String key, Boolean writeAccess) +233
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ReflectMethod(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, Boolean client, XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, String defaultNs) +1965

[InvalidOperationException: Method WebService1.Insert can not be reflected.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ReflectMethod(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, Boolean client, XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, String defaultNs) +6262
   System.Web.Services.Description.SoapProtocolReflector.ReflectMethod() +137
   System.Web.Services.Description.ProtocolReflector.ReflectBinding(ReflectedBinding reflectedBinding) +1577
   System.Web.Services.Description.ProtocolReflector.Reflect() +641
   System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionReflector.ReflectInternal(ProtocolReflector[] reflectors) +559
   System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionReflector.Reflect(Type type, String url) +109
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerType..ctor(Type type, String uri, Boolean excludeSchemeHostPortFromCachingKey) +230
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol.Initialize() +472
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing) +122

[InvalidOperationException: Unable to handle request.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing) +325
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +171

[InvalidOperationException: Failed to handle request.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +346
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +209
   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +47
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +226
   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +145

       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248
```

Please suggest me if i am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Your `public int Insert(Test obj)` is decorated as web service method.
Later you can see that `Test` inherits from `System.Web.Services.WebService`. All webservice methods/objects (in this case input parameter `Test`) should be xml-serializable; best practice is to use simple POCO classes, that expose just the fields you should expose; definitely not complex objects like all inherited stuff from `WebService`. So my advise - drop the inheritance between `Test` and `System.Web.Services.WebService`.

Like:

```
public class Test {
 ...
}
```